# Why is the stack address lower than that of heap in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

As we all know, stack address are higher than heap addresses in **Process Address Space**. But when I wrote a program to verify it in VS2010, I got some trouble.**The stack has an address lower than heap**, even lower than that of Data Segment. the program is shown as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "malloc.h"
static int g_a=123;
int g_b=123;
int main()
{
    static int a=123;
    int b=123;
    float c[10]={0};
    int *p1=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *p2=(int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
}
```

Here are their address according to the VS2010:

```
&g_a    0x01097038 
&g_b    0x0109703c
&a      0x01097040

&b      0x002af7a8
c       0x002af778

p1      0x00571500
p2      0x00571540
```

Obviously, the pointer p1 , which points to  an array on the heap, has a bigger address than &b, which is on the stack. That's why?

PS:sorry for the absence of picture due to by my poor reputation, or I could describe my question more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "As we all know, stack address are higher than heap addresses in Process Address Space."

Your assumption here is false.  The stack and heap are both allocated from the process's virtual address space and they may, for all intents and purposes, be located practically anywhere in that address space.

Comment: Thank u for help, but I wonder who is in charge of allocating address for stock and heap, the compiler or OS? I found many books had the same assumption when they elaborated the process's virtual address under Linux. If giving identical compiler, will Windows have the same memory layout as Linux?

Comment: On Windows, it is the responsibility of the operating system.